# Problems when close port

Tags: c#, serial-port, ioexception

I'm reading Arduino information into C# but when I want to stop reading the info by pressing the btnStop I always get " IOException was unhandled " why?

Error shown is commented below. 
The C# codes are as follows:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = txtPortName.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Open();

        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
        serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
    }

    void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Data = serialPort1.ReadLine(); //----->>>ERROR SHOWN HERE
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
        }
        catch (IOException ex5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + ex5);
        }
    }

    void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtData.AppendText(Data + "\n");
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex2)
        {
            txtData.AppendText("Close error: " + ex2 + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because nobody is handling that exception? you can handle it and stop reading if you want, using a `try / catch` blcok

Comment: Hi Noctis, I have edited the codes but still getting the same error.
The edited codes are shown above

Comment: The behavior you're seeing seems perfectly normal to me. That is, if you close the port while there's an outstanding read operation, the operation will complete with an exception (I'd expect `ObjectDisposedException`, but I can believe the `SerialPort` class throws something else). The only thing I see wrong with your code is that you are subscribing to `DataReceived` twice.